# Pandas convert UNIX time to multiple different timezones depending on column value

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone, dst

I have a pandas dataframe with UNIX timestamps (these are integers and not time objects). The observations occur in multiple geographic locations, and therefore multiple timezones. **I'd like to convert the UNIX timestamp into local time (in a new column) for each of these timezones, based on the geography of the observation** (this information is in a column of the dataframe).

Simple working example:

Creating the dataframe:

```
c1=[1546555701, 1546378818, 1546574677, 1546399159, 1546572278]
c2=['America/Detroit','America/Chicago','America/Los_Angeles','America/Los_Angeles','America/Detroit']

df3=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(c1,c2)),columns=['utc','tz'])

print(df3)
```

Expected output:

```
          utc                   tz
0  1546555701      America/Detroit
1  1546378818      America/Chicago
2  1546574677  America/Los_Angeles
3  1546399159  America/Los_Angeles
4  1546572278      America/Detroit
```

Current attempt:

```
df3['date_time']=pd.to_datetime(df3['utc'],unit='s')
print(df3)
```

Returns:

```
          utc                   tz           date_time
0  1546555701      America/Detroit 2019-01-03 22:48:21
1  1546378818      America/Chicago 2019-01-01 21:40:18
2  1546574677  America/Los_Angeles 2019-01-04 04:04:37
3  1546399159  America/Los_Angeles 2019-01-02 03:19:19
4  1546572278      America/Detroit 2019-01-04 03:24:38
```

This converts to a datetime object, **but I am unsure how to control the timezone** (I presume it gives me the time in my local timezone). It is certainly not based off the 'tz' column.

I have looked at pandas' [tz_convert()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert.html) function and the [arrow package](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), but have not been able to figure out how to make these work. I am open to other solutions as well. **I am concerned not only with timezone, but also making sure that daylight savings time is properly handled.**

Comment: These aren't UTC timestamps. They may be Unix timestamps. This isn't nitpicking. Outside Unix systems programming a timestamp typically means a full ISO8601 timestamp. In databases the `timestamp` type or its equivalents are a date+time value

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you are correct, I have altered the question accordingly.

Comment: if you just need to *work* with those timestamp, I'd suggest to leave it in UTC and keep the time zone information. I'd only convert to a specific tz if you need it for a presentation or something (need it to be human-readable).

Comment: @MrFuppes I need to be able to compare observations at (for example) 5:00 am in Detroit to what happens at 5:00 in Boston. This seems to necessitate this conversion, no? I'm (probably obviously) new to working with timestamps, so I am open to suggestions and improved workflows.

Comment: I've made another edit; mixed time zones are fine but you can't use the `dt` accessor, so individual timestamp attributes are a bit more difficult to extract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming POSIX timestamps (seconds since 1970-01-01 UTC), you can directly convert to UTC with keyword utc=True.

```
import pandas as pd

c1=[1546555701, 1546378818, 1546574677, 1546399159, 1546572278]
c2=['America/Detroit','America/Chicago','America/Los_Angeles','America/Los_Angeles','America/Detroit']

df3=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(c1,c2)),columns=['utc','tz'])
df3['date_time']=pd.to_datetime(df3['utc'], unit='s', utc=True)

# df3['date_time']
# 0   2019-01-03 22:48:21+00:00
# 1   2019-01-01 21:40:18+00:00
# 2   2019-01-04 04:04:37+00:00
# 3   2019-01-02 03:19:19+00:00
# 4   2019-01-04 03:24:38+00:00
# Name: date_time, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

You can then apply a time zone to each value using apply, e.g.

```
def setTZ(row):
    return row['date_time'].tz_convert(row['tz'])

df3['date_time']=df3.apply(lambda r: setTZ(r), axis=1)

# df3
#           utc                   tz                  date_time
# 0  1546555701      America/Detroit  2019-01-03 17:48:21-05:00
# 1  1546378818      America/Chicago  2019-01-01 15:40:18-06:00
# 2  1546574677  America/Los_Angeles  2019-01-03 20:04:37-08:00
# 3  1546399159  America/Los_Angeles  2019-01-01 19:19:19-08:00
# 4  1546572278      America/Detroit  2019-01-03 22:24:38-05:00
```

Note that with mixed time zones, you can't use the `dt` accessor for the Series. You need iterative code instead, e.g.

```
df3['date_time'].apply(lambda t: t.hour)
```

to get the hour for each datetime. A way around this would be to create a column that has local time but is not time zone aware:

```
def toLocalTime(row):
    return row['date_time'].tz_convert(row['tz']).replace(tzinfo=None)

df3['local_time'] = df3.apply(lambda r: toLocalTime(r), axis=1)
```

Comment: I assume that tz_convert() also deals with daylight savings, correct?

Comment: @amquack: yes it does. And you're right, for comparisons as you mention, it seems easier just to convert to the time zones. Since you have IANA time zone names, this should not cause any trouble. However, since you have mixed time zones, the `dt` accessor won't work - which can be a bit of a pain because you need interative code.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to do this without going row-by-row. You mentioned the dt accessor (I'm not sure what that is). But I'm wondering if this is a useful tool to speed things up by sorting by timezone prior to doing the conversion. I ask because this has become the bottleneck in my process. The initial "to_datetime() function is extremely quick, but the timezone conversion is quite slow (I think because it is line-by-line)

Comment: @amquack: for mixed time zones not to my knowledge. That's also why I suggested to keep it in UTC, because that part is fast.