# Speed up datetime conversion to mixed time zones - Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone

**Note:** This is a followup to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64771881/pandas-convert-unix-time-to-multiple-different-timezones-depending-on-column-val?noredirect=1#comment114523497_64771881) question.

**Problem Summary:** I have a pandas dataframe with UNIX timestamps as integers without any time information. I need to convert these to specific timezones (and then make them timezone naive objects). The problem is that doing this conversion as an iteration over each line is quite intensive, and currently makes up about 60% of my processing time (even more in this simplified example). I believe this can be reduced by using additional pandas datetime functionality, but I am having difficulty figuring out how to do this. To give scale, I need to run code over thousands of files that have a couple/few million observations each.

**Example:**

```
import pandas as pd
import time

#creating data:
n_obs=750000 # need to be a multiple of 15

l1=[1546555701, 1546378818, 1546574677, 1546399159, 1546572278]
l2=['America/Detroit','America/Chicago','America/Los_Angeles']
c1=l1*(int(n_obs/5))
c2=l2*(int(n_obs/3))

df=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(c1,c2)),columns=['timestamp','tz'])

print(df)

# operations:
sort_dict={}
tz_list=df['tz'].unique()

for x in tz_list:
    df_temp=df[df['tz']==x]
    sort_dict[x]=df_temp

def setTZ(row,x):
    return row['date_time'].tz_convert(x).replace(tzinfo=None)
    
for x in [tz_list[0]]: # I just time the first iteration of the loop for simplicity
    tic = time.perf_counter()
    sort_dict[x]['date_time']=pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'],unit='s',utc=True)
    toc = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'to_datetime() completed in {toc-tic:0.4f} seconds')
    
    # the above works quite quickly, but the problem is in the following lines:
    tic = time.perf_counter()
    sort_dict[x]['date_time']=sort_dict[x].apply(lambda row: setTZ(row,x), axis=1)
    toc = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'setTZ() completed in {toc-tic:0.4f} seconds')

    tic = time.perf_counter()
    sort_dict[x]['date']=sort_dict[x].apply(lambda row: row['date_time'].date(),axis=1)
    toc = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'create date column with .date() completed in {toc-tic:0.4f} seconds')

    tic = time.perf_counter()
    sort_dict[x]['time']=sort_dict[x].apply(lambda row: row['date_time'].time(),axis=1)
    toc = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'create time column with .time() completed in {toc-tic:0.4f} seconds')
```

**Output:**

```
to_datetime() completed in 0.0311 seconds
setTZ() completed in 26.3287 seconds
create date column with .date() completed in 3.2471 seconds
create time column with .time() completed in 3.2625 seconds
# I also have a SettingWithCopyWarning error from my code, which I think comes from how I'm overwriting the dictionaries
```

**Takeaways:**
The setTZ() function is incredibly slow. I think this is because I'm iterating line-by-line over the code to make this conversion. to_datetime() is extremely quick. If there was a way to incorporate the timezone and lose the time-aware (since I'll be comparing observations at the same time across timezones) that would be ideal. Creating the date and time columns are slow compared to the to_datetime() function, but quick relative to the setTZ() function. Optimizing these would be nice.

**Possible solution:**
I am guessing that I can harness some of panda's datetime functions, such as tz_localize() and tz_convert(), but I need to be able to convert the column of my pandas dataframe to a datetime Array. It's unclear to me how I might do this. I'm sure other solutions exist as well.

Comment: I think this is a good question; the point is the localization to a certain time zone (not the conversion of seconds since the epoch to datetime datatype). However, I doubt that you can "vectorize" the operation: for each timestamp-timezone combination, you need a specific lookup of UTC offset and DST setting in the tz database. Since both parameters are subject to political decisions, they change over time. So no way around dedicated look-ups for each timestamp (if you want to keep the procedure generally applicable).

Comment: side note: have a look at the [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/timeit.html) module for comparing computation speed

Comment: side note #2: just noticed you want to extract date and time separately; if you take the naive datetime column (no mixed time zones), you can get that much faster by `df['datetime'].dt.date` or `df['datetime'].dt.time` respectively (check if you actually need these as separate columns if you have it all in the datetime column). see also [dt accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html).

Comment: @MrFuppes The actual output needed is the date and time columns separately (I will remove the date_time column). My target output has the original UNIX column plus date and time columns. Perhaps there is a quicker way to simply convert the UNIX column into these two columns so that I can skip creating this intermediate date_time column?

Comment: since UNIX seconds since the epoch do not distinguish date & time (it's just one number): no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a dataframe as described and extended to a moderate 50k rows

```
from datetime import datetime
from backports.zoneinfo import ZoneInfo # backports not needed with Python 3.9
import pandas as pd

c1 = [1546555701, 1546378818, 1546574677, 1546399159, 1546572278]*10000
c2 = ['America/Detroit','America/Chicago','America/Los_Angeles','America/Los_Angeles','America/Detroit']*10000
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'utc': c1, 'tz': c2})

df3['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df3['utc'], unit='s', utc=True)
```

besides using the pandas built-in `tz_convert` iteratively, you could also use a list comprehension with pandas' [itertuples](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) + Python's [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) & [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html):

```
def toLocalTime_pd(row): # as given
    return row['datetime'].tz_convert(row['tz']).replace(tzinfo=None)

def localTime_dt(df):
    return [datetime.fromtimestamp(row.utc, tz=ZoneInfo(row.tz)).replace(tzinfo=None) for row in df.itertuples()]
```

In direct comparison, the ***list comp performs better by ~x8*** for the synthetic example df:

```
%timeit df3.apply(lambda r: toLocalTime_pd(r), axis=1)
1.85 s ± 17.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit localTime_dt(df3)
217 ms ± 7.55 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: This works much faster. Unfortunately it does not appear to keep the time conversion to the timezone. I have slightly altered the `localTime_dt()` function so that it takes a timezone argument: `def localTime_dt(df,tzone): return [datetime.fromtimestamp(row.utc, tz=ZoneInfo(tzone)).replace(tzinfo=None) for row in df.itertuples()]` If I test this on a copy of the same dataframe, but with a different `tzone`, I get the same resulting output for both dataframes, despite them having different timezones

Comment: @amquack: yes, `.replace(tzinfo=None)` removes the time zone information. It just leaves the value with the correct time of that time zone. If you ultimately want a separate date and time column, time zone is mostly irrelevant anyway. Remove the `.replace(tzinfo=None)`, and observe what changes...

Comment: Ignore the comments I had regarding it not working - I figured out the error in how I was testing it. I think things are working properly now!